# Strange behavior saving a file into Azure blob storage

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am using `@azure/storage-blob:^12.8.0, @azure/storage-queue: ^12.7.0` packages to authenticate and connect to Azure blob storage, authentication goes through Managed Identities and the destination granted access with `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role, below is my code

```
const credentialOptions = {
    managedIdentityClientId: process.env.MANAGED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID
};

const CONTAINER_NAME = 'C1';
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions);
const blobSvc = new BlobServiceClient(process.env.STORAGE_HOST, credential);
const containerClient = blobSvc.getContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME);

export const store = async (file: string, folder: string) => {    
    const fileName = path.basename(file);
    const blob = `${folder}/${fileName}`;
    try {
        console.debug(`starting store ${blob}...`);      
        const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob);
        await blobClient.uploadFile(file);
        console.debug('store done.');
        return blob;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);       
        throw Error(err);
    }
};


// in other module 
import {store} from 'BlobStorageHelper';

store('folder1/folder2/folder3', '/temporary/path/to/the/file.jpg');
```

everything works except that the file is stored in the wrong place, for example, by calling `store('folder1/folder2/folder3', 'path/file.jpg')` I expect the file to be stored at `folder1/folder2/folder3/file.jpg` but the file gets stored at `C1/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.jpg` **C1** is the name of the container which is wrong and should not happen, the code runs as Azure functions node.

to make it clear, the expectation is

- C1 (the container)

  - folder1

    - folder2

      - folder3

        - file.jpg

but the actual result is

- C1 (the container)

  - **C1**

    - folder1

      - folder2

        - folder3

          - file.jpg

Any idea ?

Comment: This is actually the correct behavior. A blob will always gets stored in a container.

Comment: @GauravMantri yes, but I guess you did not understand the issue correctly, the file is stored always in a container but the blob's path should not have the container's name in it, in the end, the file is stored in the container but the name of the container is duplicated in the blob's path.

Comment: Hi @Bahram,  check with   `const blob = ${folder}/${fileName}` this path i think your passing container name along with the folder structure

Comment: Hi @ShrutiJoshi-MT, that was my first guess too but I checked the logs and `console.debug('starting store ${blob}...');  ` shows that the blob path is correct (without container name). I thought that maybe the Azure API messes up with the path but most of the code example on the internet show that the code is just fine.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for how you are calling your `store` method?

Comment: @GauravMantri, I did, also I put more logs and I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the folder and file name and the final blob name is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong value coming from the AppSettings which was not obvious in the code. it should be `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net` but instead, it was `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerName`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code , I tried this code in my system able to store the file with folder structure in azure container

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString("Connection String");
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const blobName="test1/test2 "+ "/" + "test"
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
const file="C: \\blobs\\test.txt"
await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(file);
console.log('\nUploading to Azure storage as blob:\n\t', blobName);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

The files are saved in container in azure storage

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the only difference I see is that you construct `BlobServiceClient` from `ConnectionString` and I construct it with `Host` and `CredentialToken`, which I don't think is related to the issue since the file is actually stored in the blob storage. the rest of your code is also very similar to mine.

Comment: is issue resolved?